# Cannot shrink ntfs partition with GParted - couldn't update MFT error

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I'm shrinking my data partition (>550 GB) to open up some space for installing Ubuntu (along side my existing Windows 7).

However, I received this message:

> ERROR(30): Couldn't update MFT own record: Read-only file system

I have checked the partition for error and defragmentation, and there was no problem. Could anyone explain what the MFT is, and how I may resolve this problem?

I attached a picture of what I was trying to do. `dev/sda2` is my Windows 7 partition, `dev/sda5` is the data partition to be shrunk.

[image]

Here is the full log

```
Shrink /dev/sda5 from 532.90 GiB to 468.96 GiB  00:00:13    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda5  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda5
start: 316625152
end: 1434202874
size: 1117577723 (532.90 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda5 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:02    ( SUCCESS )

ntfsresize -i -f -v /dev/sda5

ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda5
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 572199793152 bytes (572200 MB)
Current device size: 572199794176 bytes (572200 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use : 186301 MB (32.6%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Estimating smallest shrunken size supported ...
File feature Last used at By inode
Multi-Record : 562170 MB 69800
$MFTMirr : 541068 MB 1
Sparse : 173572 MB 6610
Ordinary : 572159 MB 13720
You might resize at 186300178432 bytes or 186301 MB (freeing 385899 MB).
Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
shrink file system  00:00:10    ( ERROR )

run simulation  00:00:10    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize --force --force -s 503538647040 --no-action /dev/sda5

ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda5
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 572199793152 bytes (572200 MB)
Current device size: 572199794176 bytes (572200 MB)
New volume size : 503538643456 bytes (503539 MB)
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use : 186301 MB (32.6%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Needed relocations : 6234476 (25537 MB)
Schedule chkdsk for NTFS consistency check at Windows boot time ...
Resetting $LogFile ... (this might take a while)
Relocating needed data ...
100.00 percent completed
ERROR(30): Couldn't update MFT own record: Read-only file system
```

Comment: I have the same error while trying to resize Windows 7 and 8.1 recovery USB disks. Maybe it's just not possible to resize?